# How to populate a listview with sections?

Tags: android

I have to fill a `ListView`. I have got a `HashMap` of objects. Now I need to populate a `ListView` with a string values from these objects. The header for section is also there in these objects. So I need to take out the section headers from these objects and then group them according to these headers and populate listview with this. How to achieve this? Anyone please help me. I tried `pinnedheadelistview`, but couldn't work it out.

Comment: Try using expandable list view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i have done:

**File: main.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/add_journalentry_menuitem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_journal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**File: list_header.xml**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_header_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
```

**File: list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- list_item.xml -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />
```

**File: list_complex.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- list_complex.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_complex_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_complex_caption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**File: add_journalentry_menuitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- list_item.xml -->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:paddingBottom="0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

**File: ListSample.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ListSample extends Activity
    {

        public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";
        public final static String ITEM_CAPTION = "caption";

        // SectionHeaders
        private final static String[] days = new String[]{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri"};

        // Section Contents
        private final static String[] notes = new String[]{"Ate Breakfast", "Ran a Marathan ...yah really", "Slept all day"};

        // MENU - ListView
        private ListView addJournalEntryItem;

        // Adapter for ListView Contents
        private SeparatedListAdapter adapter;

        // ListView Contents
        private ListView journalListView;

        public Map<String, ?> createItem(String title, String caption)
            {
                Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);
                item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);
                return item;
            }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
            {
                super.onCreate(icicle);

                // Sets the View Layer
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                // Interactive Tools
                final ArrayAdapter<String> journalEntryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.add_journalentry_menuitem, new String[]{"Add Journal Entry"});

                // AddJournalEntryItem
                addJournalEntryItem = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.add_journalentry_menuitem);
                addJournalEntryItem.setAdapter(journalEntryAdapter);
                addJournalEntryItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long duration)
                            {
                                String item = journalEntryAdapter.getItem(position);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                    });

                // Create the ListView Adapter
                adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);
                ArrayAdapter<String> listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, notes);

                // Add Sections
                for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++)
                    {
                        adapter.addSection(days[i], listadapter);
                    }

                // Get a reference to the ListView holder
                journalListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_journal);

                // Set the adapter on the ListView holder
                journalListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                // Listen for Click events
                journalListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long duration)
                            {
                                String item = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                    });
            }

    }
```

**File: SeparatedListAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        public final Map<String, Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String, Adapter>();
        public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
        public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

        public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context)
            {
                headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);
            }

        public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter)
            {
                this.headers.add(section);
                this.sections.put(section, adapter);
            }

        public Object getItem(int position)
            {
                for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
                    {
                        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
                        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

                        // check if position inside this section
                        if (position == 0) return section;
                        if (position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);

                        // otherwise jump into next section
                        position -= size;
                    }
                return null;
            }

        public int getCount()
            {
                // total together all sections, plus one for each section header
                int total = 0;
                for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
                    total += adapter.getCount() + 1;
                return total;
            }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount()
            {
                // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections
                int total = 1;
                for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
                    total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
                return total;
            }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position)
            {
                int type = 1;
                for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
                    {
                        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
                        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

                        // check if position inside this section
                        if (position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
                        if (position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);

                        // otherwise jump into next section
                        position -= size;
                        type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
                    }
                return -1;
            }

        public boolean areAllItemsSelectable()
            {
                return false;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position)
            {
                return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                int sectionnum = 0;
                for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
                    {
                        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
                        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

                        // check if position inside this section
                        if (position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
                        if (position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

                        // otherwise jump into next section
                        position -= size;
                        sectionnum++;
                    }
                return null;
            }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
            {
                return position;
            }

    }
```

Try this and let me know if any issues happy coding :)